# calling `str` on a object errors out if the ggplot2 package is loaded

Tags: r, debugging, ggplot2

The following was tested with `R 2.15.3`, `ggplot2 0.9.3.1` and `gtable 0.1.2` on Debian squeeze.

In the course of debugging this ggplot2 issue
[multiple calls to annotation_custom fail in certain cases](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/817), I came across something I don't know how to debug. I've created a repository in Bitbucket with the relevant information 
[github-ggplot2-817](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/github-ggplot2-817).

The relevant [README](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/github-ggplot2-817/src/tip/README) from that repos is copied below.
If you don't want to use Mercurial, the relevant
file with serialized R data can be downloaded directly from [addgrob.asc.save](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/github-ggplot2-817/downloads/addgrob.asc.save).

To reproduce `addgrob.asc.save`, you could use the Debian packaging in https://bitbucket.org/faheem/gtable-debian, or if you prefer, just the patch to `gtable`, namely [gtableaddgrob.diff](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/gtable-debian/src/tip/patches/gtableaddgrob.diff), along with the script [save.R](https://bitbucket.org/faheem/github-ggplot2-817/src/tip/save.R).

Summary of the issue: running R's `str` function on an object (here called `x`)
gives an error if `ggplot2` is loaded, but not otherwise. I'm  not sure what is going on,
so any pointers would be appreciated.

```
###############################################################
```

To reproduce this bug, do the following.

Start R. Then

```
> ls()
character(0)
> load("addgrob.asc.save")
> ls()
[1] "grobs"  "layout" "x"

> str(x, max.level=1)
List of 10
 $ grobs   :List of 8
 $ layout  :'data.frame':       8 obs. of  7 variables:
   $ widths  :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:6] 1.5 6.096 0.762 1.961 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ heights :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:7] 1.5 2.53 1.52 6.1 6.1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ respect : logi FALSE
 $ rownames: NULL
 $ colnames: NULL
 $ name    : chr "layout"
 $ gp      : NULL
 $ vp      : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gtable" "grob" "gDesc"

## Now update x
> x$grobs <- c(x$grobs, grobs)
> x$layout <- rbind(x$layout, layout)

> str(x, max.level=1)
List of 10
 $ grobs   :List of 11
 $ layout  :'data.frame':       11 obs. of  7 variables:
   $ widths  :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:6] 1.5 6.096 0.762 1.961 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ heights :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:7] 1.5 2.53 1.52 6.1 6.1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ respect : logi FALSE
 $ rownames: NULL
 $ colnames: NULL
 $ name    : chr "layout"
 $ gp      : NULL
 $ vp      : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gtable" "grob" "gDesc"

> library(ggplot2)

> str(x, max.level=1)
List of 11
 $ grobs   :List of 11
 $ layout  :'data.frame':       11 obs. of  7 variables:
   $ widths  :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:6] 1.5 6.096 0.762 1.961 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ heights :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:7] 1.5 2.53 1.52 6.1 6.1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ respect : logi FALSE
 $ rownames: NULL
 $ colnames: NULL
 $ name    : chr "layout"
 $ gp      : NULL
 $ vp      : NULL
 $ NA:Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Loading `ggplot2` does not cause the earlier version of `x` to error
out `str`.

```
> ls()
character(0)
> load("addgrob.asc.save")
l> ls()
[1] "grobs"  "layout" "x"     
> library(ggplot2)
> str(x, max.level=1)
List of 8
 $ grobs   :List of 8
 $ layout  :'data.frame':       8 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ widths  :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:6] 1.5 6.096 0.762 1.961 0 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ heights :Class 'unit'  atomic [1:7] 1.5 2.53 1.52 6.1 6.1 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "mm"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 7
 $ respect : logi FALSE
 $ rownames: NULL
 $ colnames: NULL
 $ name    : chr "layout"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gtable" "grob" "gDesc"
```

The output of traceback() is

```
> traceback()
2: str.default(x, max.level = 1)
1: str(x, max.level = 1)
```

ADDENDUM: In Python it is possible to set things up so that all lines of code called when a function is executed are written to a file.This can be rather voluminous, but if this was possible in R, it would help to clarify things. I did a Google search, but all I came up with were various debugging utilities.

ADDENDUM2: I've created the issue [The str function fails with error on ggplot2 objects](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/820) for this.

Comment: @DWin It sounds like you didn't run the update code. First `x$grobs <- c(x$grobs, grobs)` then `x$layout <- rbind(x$layout, layout)`. Look at the recipe again. You would get 8 list elements before, but not after.

Comment: What does traceback() say after the error, and does it help to use `options(error=recover)`?

Comment: I added the output of `traceback()`. Adding `options(error=recover)` makes no difference to the traceback. However, with that option, when the error happens it drops me in a debugger, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Right. Can reproduce on R 3.0.1 with ggplot2_0.9.3.1. Will delete earlier comment. Still not sure it matters very much, though.

Comment: I thinkthis is an @hadley question.

Comment: Problems of this nature are usually caused by an S3 length method that is inconsistent with the name method (str isn't terribly flexible in this respect).  That would explain why you only see it when certain packages are loaded - those packages are providing the methods.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for replying. Can you provide a link with further details or an example? How would one track down exactly what the problem is, and what would a fix look like? It is not a major problem, but is quite a nuisance when debugging, when I at least use `str`.

Comment: Call names and length on the object. Do they agree? Otherwise, you'll need to figure out how str works.

Comment: @hadley Sorry, I've no idea what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Example: `names(x)` and `length(x)`. I'm not sure this question has wide enough relevance to justify the time being spent on it. Aren't you being a bit OCD about this? To be honest I'd sooner hadley spent his valuable time on the next versions of his many packages or on `ggplot3`.

Answer (score 2):

The error can be recreated more simply with :

```
x[11]
```

I think what is happening is that your 'x'-object was created in a working environment that had "["-methods for 'gtable' objects. You are now bringing this back into a workspace where there were none at first, and then with the loading of ggplot2 there are now some sort of "["-methods referenced by ggplot2, even though the `gtables` package is still not loaded.

I am unable to get the problem to go away with loading pkg:gtable. But I am not convinced that 'gtable' is a properly formed package, since `sessionInfo()` refuses to report its registration despite `require(gtable)` reporting success.

```
> require(gtable)
Loading required package: gtable
> `[.gtable`(x, 11)
Error: could not find function "[.gtable"
No suitable frames for recover()
> x[11]
Error in if (any(index < 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: x[11]
2: `[.gtable`(x, 11)
3: x$heights[rows]
4: `[.unit`(x$heights, rows)

Selection: 0
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.0 RC (2013-03-31 r62463)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      grDevices datasets  splines   graphics  utils     stats    
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] gtable_0.1.2        RCurl_1.95-4.1      bitops_1.0-5       
 [4] data.table_1.8.8    gplots_2.11.0       MASS_7.3-26        
 [7] KernSmooth_2.23-10  caTools_1.14        gdata_2.12.0       
[10] gtools_2.7.1        ggplot2_0.9.3.1     gridExtra_0.9.1    
[13] HH_2.3-36           colorspace_1.2-1    reshape_0.8.4      
[16] plyr_1.8            latticeExtra_0.6-24 RColorBrewer_1.0-5 
[19] leaps_2.9           multcomp_1.2-17     mvtnorm_0.9-9994   
[22] rms_3.6-3           Hmisc_3.10-1        survival_2.37-4    
[25] sos_1.3-5           brew_1.0-6          lattice_0.20-15    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] cluster_1.14.4  dichromat_2.0-0 digest_0.6.3    fortunes_1.5-0 
 [5] labeling_0.1    munsell_0.4     proto_0.3-10    reshape2_1.2.2 
 [9] scales_0.2.3    stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.0.0
```

(I do have gtable 0.1.2 installed.)

Addendum: can reproduce with this code:

```
test <- data.frame(x=1:20, y=21:40, 
                  facet.a=rep(c(1,2), 10), 
                  facet.b=rep(c(1,2), each=20))
p <- qplot(data=test, x=x, y=y, facets=facet.b~facet.a)
# get gtable object
z <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
length(z)
#[1] 16
z[16]  # drops into browser
```

Comment: I think you should be using `x[[11]]` etc above. After all, this is a list. Not sure why you are using `x[11]`. E.g. `x[[8]]`  gives value "layout" but `x[8]` gives the same error as for `x[11]`. Ok, I guess you're referring to a special `[]` operator, but why is it incorrect to get an error for `x[11]`?

Comment: "That , Detective, is the right question. Program terminated."

Comment: Sorry, that last should have been "why is it incorrect to get an error for x[8]?"

Comment: Look. I don't know exactly what is broken in `[.gtable` dispatch or code. The code is there, despite the fact that the package does not show up with `sessionInfo()`.. All I know is that functions calling `[.gtable`, as would `x[\anything\]`, get thrown to the error handlers. I'm not good enough with browser investigation to track it down, so the question will need to be examined by @hadley or @koshke since they wrote the program.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the problem is that `str.default` looks at the length of the gtable, which is defined as the number of grobs, but then iterates over it and runs into non-existent elements because `[.gtable` is written to access cells of the gtable (matrix of cells), not the grobs, and those cells can be fewer than the number of grobs.

I can think of two approaches to remedy this problem,

1. define a `str.gtable` methood providing more compact information (and fixing this indexing error)
2. redefine `[.gtable` for one index (g[1]) to access the list of grobs (equiv. the rows of the layout data.frame), not the "cell matrix"

Here's a proposed `str.gtable` function; I wonder if there are clear rules to define those (the default method is quite a beast),

```
str.gtable <- function(object, ...){
  cat(c("gtable, containing \ngrobs (", 
        length(object[["grobs"]]), "), with names :"), sep="")
  utils::str(names(object[["grobs"]]))
  cat("layout :\n")
  utils::str(object[["layout"]])
  cat("widths :\nunit vector of length", 
      length(object[["widths"]]), "\n")
  cat("heights :\nunit vector of length", 
      length(object[["heights"]]), "\n")
  for(element in c("respect", "rownames", 
                   "name", "gp", "vp")){
    cat(element, ":\n")
    utils::str(object[[element]])
  }
}
library(gridExtra)

g <- tableGrob(head(iris))
str(g)
```

yielding

```
gtable, containing 
grobs (84), with names : chr [1:84] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ...
layout :
'data.frame':   84 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ t   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 $ l   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ b   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 $ r   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ z   : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0 ...
 $ clip: chr  "on" "on" "on" "on" ...
 $ name: chr  "rowhead-fg" "rowhead-fg" "rowhead-fg" "rowhead-fg" ...
widths :
unit vector of length 6 
heights :
unit vector of length 7 
respect :
 logi FALSE
rownames :
 NULL
name :
 chr "rowhead-fg"
gp :
 NULL
vp :
 NULL
```

Comment: Hi baptiste. Unfortunately I don't remember anything about this question. It has been years. Can you add a comment to the corresponding issue? I see hadley helpfully closed it, like all my other bugs, but I think it is still possible to add a comment. Do you have a patch for this problem?

Comment: @hadley, any thoughts on including something like this in gtable?

Comment: baptiste, I saw your comment in the issue, but why not put your suggested code directly into the issue?

Comment: well, I'm not confident about the fate of those github issues. For now, gridExtra (dev) has a version of str.gtable.

Comment: I'm not clear what that means. Did you commit some code to some auxiliary project?